# Convert excel file (.xlsx) to json

Tags: python, json, pandas

I have a xlsx file

| Country name | Country code |
| --- | --- |
| IN | India |
| SL | Sri Lanka |

I want to convert this to a json in the format

```
json = {
       {"Name":"India",
        "Code":"IN"},
       {"Name":"Sri Lanka",
        "Code":"SL"}
       }
```

I tried load the excel file using the pandas and convert them to json but i am getting

```
json = {
       "India":"IN",
        "Sri Lanka":"SL"
       }
```

Comment: While the question has been answered, it's probably worth noting that your desired format is not valid json.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `pandas` to accomplish this. First you can read the xlsx file into a DataFrame using [pandas.read_excel](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html)

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel('your_sheet.xlsx')
```

then you can write that DataFrame back out as json using [pandas.DataFrame.to_json](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_json.html)

```
df.to_json('your_data.json', orient='records')
```

or if you want it as a json string instead of writing to file

```
json_data = df.to_json(orient='records')
```

Note that to achieve the output format you described you want to pass `orient='records'`

> The format of the JSON string:
>
> - ‘split’ : dict like {‘index’ -> [index], ‘columns’ -> [columns], >- ‘data’ -> [values]}
> - ‘records’ : list like [{column -> value}, … , {column -> value}]
> - ‘index’ : dict like {index -> {column -> value}}
> - ‘columns’ : dict like {column -> {index -> value}}
> - ‘values’ : just the values array
> - ‘table’ : dict like {‘schema’: {schema}, ‘data’: {data}}
>   Describing the data, where data component is like `orient='records'`.

Answer (score 0):

try:
`df.to_json(orient="records")`